# IntStream.boxed() vs for loop | Performance

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I was writing a piece of code where I had a String[] and a method which takes this String[] and returns Byte[] maintaining the string-Byte pair with the position where few of the Byte could be null. Eventually, I have to transform the Byte and get a map of with key as string from String[] and value as the return of transformation. This is how I implemented the same in Java 8 streams:

```
IntStream.range(0, productReferences.length)
            .filter(index -> (null!= productsPrice[index])).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(position -> productReferences[position],
                    position ->callSomeMethod(productsPrice[position])));
```

where productReference is String[] and productsPrice[] is Byte[] array.

Now the question is IntStream.boxed() method. Internally, it boxes int to Integer so that it returns a Stream which I believe is a costlier operation.

Other way would be use java for loop

```
    for(int i=0;i<productReferences.length; i++){
    if (productsPrice[index]==null) continue;
    //other code
}
```

What is the best way of handling such kind of scenario? I understand the reason to create IntStream but if I can actually have the index in collect method without boxed() method thus avoiding the boxing?

Comment: Premature optimization is root of all evil - unless you absolutely need that extra performance, stick with what is easier for you to understand.

Comment: @Mac70 I totally agree to what you say sir. :-) Still an addition to knowledge kitty is always +1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) operation that you have on `IntStream` instead of boxing it into a `Stream<Integer>`.

```
IntStream.range(0, productReferences.length)
         .filter(index -> productsPrice[index] != null)
         .collect(
            HashMap::new,
            (m, i) -> m.put(productReferences[i], callSomeMethod(productsPrice[i])),
            Map::putAll
         );
```

This won't box every index into an `Integer` since the consumer part of the collector takes an [`ObjIntConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ObjIntConsumer.html); so `i` in the code above is an `int`. [As Holger noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268658/intstream-boxed-vs-for-loop-performance/39269783#comment65882968_39269783), the initial code, using `Collectors.toMap` would throw an exception in the case of duplicate keys, when this version would overwrite the value.

You would still need to benchmark the two solutions on your real data to see if that brings an improvement.

Comment: The assumption that this can be a potential performance improvement is the reason why `IntStream` exists. But it should be noted that there is a semantic difference. `toMap` will throw an exception, if there’s a duplicate key, whereas this variant will silently overwrite. By the way, the value is supposed to be `callSomeMethod(productsPrice[position])`, not `productsPrice[position]`.

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense.. A classic case of supplier accumulator and finisher.. And   since no auto boxing, better performant than mine approach. Thanks to both of you! :-)